# How can I tell what 3rd-party cookies are being loaded from my site?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

Suppose I run `bar.com`. When a user visits `bar.com`, various 3rd party cookies are loaded: google analytics, facebook etc. As the admin of `bar.com`, I want to keep a list of 3rd party cookies being loaded on that site. Is there a way to do this through javascript? Something like `document.cookie` only gives me the cookie for `bar.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript, running in the context of the page, only has access to cookies belonging to that domain.

There is no mechanism to access cookies from other domains, and security restrictions are put in place to prevent access when there might be a possibility (e.g. you can't read a `Set-Cookie` response header from a response to a `fetch` request because it is defined as a *forbidden header* in the CORS spec).

You need to use some other mechanism to find out about third-party cookies such as the developer tools or a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

One way, if you are able to use chrome, devtools allows you to view cookies set one each relevant domain.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies#open (note example in link only shows a case where one domain is in use)
Important to note that different cookies may be set on different visits though

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the chrome extension "EditThisCookie" which allows you to not only view each cookie but their values and various properties in depth:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en